# php variable not saving output of query

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and have been trying to find out where I am going wrong in the statement below:

```
if(empty($_POST['datepickere']))
    {
        $purchaseorderdate = mysql_query("SELECT purchaseorderDMY FROM purchaseorders WHERE Servicetag = '$_POST[stage]'");

    }
else
    {
        $purchaseorderdate = "$_POST[datepickere]";
    }
```

The else statement executes just fine however the if statement does not save the output of the query to `"$purchaseorderdate"`

Can someone please give me a pointer as to where I am going wrong? Sorry if there is syntax error or something like that.

> datepickere = A field in my HTML form.
>
> purchaseorderDMY = The field in the DB where the datepickere is saved
>   when a new content is added

Comment: You should not use `$_POST` directly in query strings by the way. It's vunerable to sql injections. And use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`. It's deprecated

Comment: And can you add information what's in `$purchaseorderdate` (e.g using `print_r()`)?

Comment: Also quotes are not necessary `$purchaseorderdate = $_POST[datepickere];`

Comment: Please, against sql injections look for PDO.

Comment: Thanks all but I am really not worried about SQL injections because the form is very internal & very small scale.

I will remove the quotes however the "IF" block is the problem. Should I use something like a mysql_result?

Comment: @SS97 You need to iterate over the result of the query. Don't use `mysql_*` anymore

Comment: @FilipKováč.. I dont know but do I have to initialize a variable in PHP? I thought it does default type casting. In this case a string.

Comment: @SS97 the problem with SQL Injections is greater than people doing bad things.  suddenly your form won't work.  and you'll wonder why.  and it will be because someone tried to insert something you never considered and it failed because the query didn't compile properly.  you need to be concerned about this - it's not hard to do it right - it's hard to clean up after doing it wrong.

Comment: @rb94, could you please elaborate very briefly if possible.

Comment: `$purchaseorderdate = mysql_query(` this is going to give you a result.  [please look at the documentation that has working, simple examples](http://php.net/mysql_result) and note the **big red area that says don't use this function**

Comment: @WEBjuju.. Ah! Thanks I will change it to mysqli.. Seems easy, yes :)

Comment: About variables you are right. They have not to be initialized but must be in current context. That mean, when you create variable in if statement, it is existing just in that if statement like in every other programming lang.

Comment: it's more than switching to mysqli.  you can't do this: `WHERE Servicetag = '$_POST[stage]'` because you are not protecting your query.  you must do this `WHERE Servicetag = '$myvar'` after doing this: `$myvar = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['stage']);`.  and note that you *must* quote your strings in `$_POST['stage']`.  please find your `php_error_log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by making a mysqli connection [(this is right out the docs)](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Now update your code snippet with more [exact copies from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
if (empty($_POST['datepickere'])) {

    $myvar = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['stage']);

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT purchaseorderDMY FROM purchaseorders WHERE Servicetag = '$myvar'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $purchaseorderdate = $row['purchaseorderDMY'];

} else {

    // you don't need to quote a variable to use it
    // but it must be quoted starting at PHP4 (a decade ago)
    $purchaseorderdate = $_POST['datepickere'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Have been crazy busy and revisited it today. All is well now.. Thanks.